# Loop through Months in Java / Android

Tags: java, android, date, loops

I want to loop through months of the year and print out.

for example:

01/2012
02/2012
03/2012
04/2012
etc...

Here is my code:

```
 Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();

 for (int i = 0; i < totalMonths; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        myDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        FinalDate = df.format(myDate.getTime());
        TextView tvNum = new TextView(this);
        tvNum.setText("      " + FinalDate);
        row.addView(tvNum);
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

It is printing out in int's

1
2
3
4
5

However, when I convert it to a date string, as seen in code above, it does this:

05/2012
06/2012
08/2012
11/2012
03/2013
08/2013

Basically, the gap of months is 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 etc... Are my calculations wrong? (showing the 1,2,3,4, etc list of int's is doing what it is supposed to be) or is there a better way through printing out months?

I just want it to go

today's date + 1 month
today's date + 2 months
etc...
this m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `i` months to the current date each time.

Therefore, the third iteration adds `2` months to the previous date, the fourth adds `3`, etc.

You should be adding just `1` month each time.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you define myDate? Outside the loop, I'm assuming? If so, then you're adding 0+0 the first time, (0+0)+1 the second time, (0+0+1)+2 the third time, etc.

To fix this, you have to define myDate inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
myDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
```

put

```
myDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

or else create a new date every time.  Currently you're manipulating your actual myDate Object.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time through desugaring

I should like to contribute the modern answer, the modern way to obtain your result. I recommend that these days you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. The others have nicely explained why your code gave an unexpected output, I am not repeating that.

```
    int noOfMonths = 13;
    YearMonth current = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Tunis"));
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfMonths; i++) {
        System.out.println(current);
        current = current.plusMonths(1);
    }
```

When I ran this snippet today, the output was:

```
2019-01
2019-02
2019-03
2019-04
2019-05
2019-06
2019-07
2019-08
2019-09
2019-10
2019-11
2019-12
2020-01
```

If you want the month names, use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM u", Locale.ENGLISH);
    int noOfMonths = 13;
    YearMonth current = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Tunis"));
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfMonths; i++) {
        System.out.println(current.format(monthFormatter));
        current = current.plusMonths(1);
    }
```

Output:

```
January 2019
February 2019
March 2019
April 2019
May 2019
June 2019
July 2019
August 2019
September 2019
October 2019
November 2019
December 2019
January 2020
```

When this question was asked nearly 7 years ago, `Calendar` was the class we had for a task like this, also when it was poorly designed and cumbersome to work with. Not any longer: java.time came out with Java 8 just a couple of years later and has also been backported to Java 6 and 7.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: nice work! @Ole V.V. thanks for sharing